# wrong mouseDown xy position when using ngx-panzoom

Tags: javascript, angular, mouseevent

right  now I am trying to create a rectangle when the user click down and click up
and it's working perfectly fine

but I am using **ngx-panzoom** to zoom and pan
and when I zoom in or out the rectangle position is not synced with where the user clicks down and up

```
get offsetX() {
  return this.container.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().x;
}

get offsetY() {
  return this.container.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().y;
}
//-------------
this.x = e.pageX - this.offsetX;
this.y = e.pageY - this.offsetY;
```

and right now I have access to the current zoom scale and try many things to find a formula but it failed

```
// this.panZoomAPI.model.zoomLevel
// this.panZoomAPI.model.pan.x
// this.panZoomAPI.model.pan.y

this.x = (e.pageX - this.offsetX) * this.panZoomAPI.model.zoomLevel;
this.y = (e.pageY - this.offsetY) * this.panZoomAPI.model.zoomLevel;
```